# lauching an EC2 Instance with AWS Explorer in Visual Studio error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-2017

I installed the AWS Explorer for Visual Studio and I tried launching various EC2-Instances. None worked.
The Error Message I get is the following:

> [image: Error]

So far I tried using the Frankfurt Region and if I am correct, the User Account for Visual Studio has full Admin access. What could be the cause of that problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to advise without the launch configuration you have used. It could be that you have selected an instance type e.g. t1.micro which is not available in Frankfurt region. You can check available instance type using:
curl -s  https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json | jq -r '.products[].attributes | select(.location == "EU (Frankfurt)" and .tenancy == "Shared") | .instanceType' | sort -u

This blog explains it well: http://rodos.haywood.org/2016/03/which-instances-are-available-in-my.html

Comment: I looked that blog up and I tried your suggested command, but I run into a problem. On executuon I get this `cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:
`

Comment: also, I tried various launch configurations and none of them worked. I also avoided t1.micro

Comment: I'm not sure about the error but for me these are supported instances. http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIR8A